# Wrong result from Mysql in Android with the same URL

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

It's my first application, and I can't get, why I'm getting different results from the PHP in app.

I got a `recyclerView` (Endless) which gets an array with objects from the adapter.
class `FromJsonToItem.java` gets the data from PHP script (which connects to MySQL database and gives back the data in JSON format) and returns it in ArrayList

When I start the app, everything works fine. I get right results from database, then app loads more data when I scroll the view. But, when I try to start another activity (Search), and then press Back button (or back in the app_bar) to return to the `MainActivity`, I got different result from Mysql. The url is the same!

I can't find what's wrong, Is it in the PHP or about the logic in my application?

MainActivity

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

    public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
        String jSonResult;
        private String jsonUrl = "/android/jsongetdata.php";
        List<Item> mItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        Context context;
        int mFromLimit = 0;
        private EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener scrollListener;

    private ItemRecyclerViewAdapter mItemRecyclerViewAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume: start");
        super.onResume();

        int itemCount = mItemList.size();
        mItemList.clear();
        mItemRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(mFromLimit,itemCount);
        getJson(jsonUrl);
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume: ends");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause: starts");
        super.onPause();

        Log.d(TAG, "onPause: ends");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starts");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(layoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
                // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
                // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to the bottom of the list
                Log.d(TAG, "onLoadMore: started");
                Log.d(TAG, "onLoadMore: Array is ====" + String.valueOf(mItemList.size()));

                mFromLimit = mFromLimit + 10;
                Log.d(TAG, "onPause: ______Mfrom limit now:" + String.valueOf(mFromLimit));
                loadNextDataFromApi(mFromLimit);
                Log.d(TAG, "onLoadMore: ends");
            }
        };
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
        mItemRecyclerViewAdapter = new ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(this, mItemList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mItemRecyclerViewAdapter);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: SetAdapter ++++++");


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ends");
    }

    public void loadNextDataFromApi(final int offset) {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadNextDataFromApi: started");
        // Send an API request to retrieve appropriate paginated data
        //  --> Send the request including an offset value (i.e `page`) as a query parameter.
        String off = String.valueOf(offset);
        String url = createUri("","","","","",off);
        getJson(url);
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mItemRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(offset, mItemList.size());
            }
        };
        Log.d(TAG, "loadNextDataFromApi: ends");
        handler.post(r);

        //  --> Deserialize and construct new model objects from the API response
        //  --> Append the new data objects to the existing set of items inside the array of items
        //  --> Notify the adapter of the new items made with `notifyItemRangeInserted()`
    }

    public void getJson(String jsonUrl) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getJson: starts");
        FromJsonToItem fromJsonToItem = new FromJsonToItem();
        fromJsonToItem.execute(jsonUrl);
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "getJson: mItems size before adding" + mItemList.size());
            mItemList.addAll(fromJsonToItem.get());
            Log.d(TAG, "getJson: mItems size after adding" + mItemList.size());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "getJson: ends");

    }



    private String createUri(String name, String category, String rating, String yearStart, String yearEnd, String limitFrom){
        Log.d(TAG, "createUri: starts");
        String uriString = jsonUrl;
        if(!(name.equals(""))){
            uriString = Uri.parse(uriString).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("name", name).toString();
        }
        if(!(category.equals(""))){
            uriString = Uri.parse(uriString).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("category", category).toString();
        }
        if(!(rating.equals(""))){
            uriString = Uri.parse(uriString).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("rating", rating).toString();
        }
        if(!(yearStart.equals(""))){
            uriString = Uri.parse(uriString).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("yearStart", yearStart).toString();
        }
        if(!(yearEnd.equals(""))){
            uriString = Uri.parse(uriString).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("yearEnd", yearEnd).toString();
        }
        if(!(limitFrom.equals(""))){
            uriString = Uri.parse(uriString).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("limitFrom", limitFrom).toString();
        }

        return uriString;

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if(id==R.id.action_search){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_films) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_series) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_cartoon) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_podborki) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

My FromJsonToItem class with connection and parsing strings

```
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.util.Log;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    /**
     * Created by moyo on 28.01.17.
     */

    class FromJsonToItem extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Item>> {

    private static final String TAG = "FromJsonToItem";
    private List<Item> mItems = null;
    private String mBaseUrl;


    @Override
    protected List<Item> doInBackground(String... params) {
        String jsonUrl = params[0];
        String jsonString = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(jsonUrl);
            mBaseUrl = jsonUrl;
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: opening connection");
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: NOW URL IS:" + mBaseUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while((jsonString=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                stringBuilder.append(jsonString+"\n");
            }
            jsonString = stringBuilder.toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: json get next string: " + jsonString);
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: connection closed");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Generate JSON object from String

        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray itemsArray = jsonData.getJSONArray("server_response");
            HashMap<String, String> fieldsMap = new HashMap<>();

            for(int i = 0; i<itemsArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonFilm = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = jsonFilm.getString("title");

                int id = jsonFilm.getInt("id");
                String shortStory = jsonFilm.getString("short_story");
                String[] categories = jsonFilm.getString("category").split(",");
                int[] intCategories = new int[categories.length];
                for(int j = 0; j < categories.length; j++)
                {
                    intCategories[j] = Integer.parseInt(categories[j]);
                }

                String xFields = jsonFilm.getString("xfields");
                xFields = xFields.replaceAll("\\\\","");
              //  Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: xfields: " + xFields);

                String[] splitXfields = xFields.split("\\|\\|");
                //fill the MAP with key,value from the xfields

                for(int j = 0; j<splitXfields.length; j++ ){
                    String temp = splitXfields[j];
                    String[] tempArray = temp.split("\\|");
                    if(tempArray.length==2){

                        fieldsMap.put(tempArray[0],tempArray[1]);
                    }

                }
              //  Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: tempArray:" + fieldsMap.toString());
                //When map is filed, starting creating Item objects

                String age = "";
                String poster = "";
                String original = "";
                String trailer = "";
                String god = "";
                String rol = "";
                String re = "";
                String country = "";
                String company = "";
                String length = "";
                String rating = "";
                String imdb = "";
                String name = "";
                String torrents = "";
                String audio = "";
                String video = "";
                String format = "";
                String size = "";
                String torrent = "";

                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fieldsMap.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    String value = entry.getValue();
                    switch(key){
                        case "poster":
                            poster = value;
                            break;
                        case "original":
                            original = value;
                            break;
                        case "treller":
                            trailer = value;
                            break;
                        case "god":
                            god = value;
                            break;
                        case "rol":
                            rol = value;
                            break;
                        case "re":
                            re = value;
                            break;
                        case "country":
                            country = value;
                            break;
                        case "comp":
                            company = value;
                            break;
                        case "prod":
                            length = value;
                            break;
                        case "rating":
                            rating = value;
                            break;
                        case "name":
                            name = value;
                            break;
                        case "age":
                            age = value;
                            break;
                        case "torrents":
                            torrents = value;
                            break;
                        case "audio":
                            audio = value;
                            break;
                        case "video":
                            video = value;
                            break;
                        case "format":
                            format = value;
                            break;
                        case "size":
                            size = value;
                            break;
                        case "torrent":
                            torrent = value;
                            break;
                        case "imdb":
                            imdb = value;
                            break;
                    }
                }

                shortStory = android.text.Html.fromHtml(shortStory).toString();
                shortStory = shortStory.replaceAll("\\\\","");

                Item item = new Item(age,audio,intCategories,company,country,format,god,id,imdb,length,name,original,poster,
                        rating,re,rol,shortStory,size,title,torrent,torrents,trailer,video);
                //Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Item" + item.toString());
               // Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: =================");

                mItems.add(item);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return mItems;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Item> items) {

    }
}
```

And PHP file with getting the data from DB
I pass the parameters in the url (if they are), which generates in

MainActivity.createUri

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$database="*****";
$username="*****";
$password="****";

$name;
$category;
$rating;
$yearStart;
$yearEnd = 2017;
$limitFrom = 0;

if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $name .="%";
}
if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
    $category = $_GET['category'];
    $category .="%";

}
if (isset($_GET['rating'])) {
    $rating = $_GET['rating'];

}
if (isset($_GET['yearStart'])) {
    $yearStart = $_GET['yearStart'];

}
if (isset($_GET['yearEnd'])) {
    $yearEnd = $_GET['yearEnd'];

}
if (isset($_GET['limitFrom'])) {
    $limitFrom = $_GET['limitFrom'];

}

$sqlYearStart = " xfields like '%dates|";
$sqlYearStart .=$yearStart;
$sqlYearStart .= "%'";

$sqlName = " and title like '%";
$sqlName .= $name;
$sqlName .= "'";


$sqlCategory = " and category like '%";
$sqlCategory .= $category;
$sqlCategory .= "'";

$sqlRating = " and (xfields like '%rating|";
$sqlRating .= $rating;
$sqlRating .= "%'";
$sqlRating .= " or xfields like '%imdb|";
$sqlRating .= $rating;
$sqlRating .= "%')";


$sql= "select dle_post.id,dle_post.title,dle_post.short_story,dle_post.xfields,dle_post.category from dle_post where";
$sql .= $sqlYearStart;
$sql .= $sqlName;
$sql .= $sqlCategory;
$sql .= $sqlRating;
$sql .= " order by dle_post.id DESC limit ";
$sql .= $limitFrom;
$sql .= ", 10;";


$con =mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
$result= mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response= array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    array_push($response,array("id"=>$row[0],"title"=>$row[1],"short_story"=>$row[2],"xfields"=>$row[3],"category"=>$row[4]));

}

$json = json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);


echo $json;
 mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

I can add a logcat message if it will help. Need a fresh look, because I'm in a deadlock

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In `onResume()` you call `getJson(jsonUrl);` but in `onCreate()` you call `getJson(url);` . Are you sure those are the exactly URLs? Log the url inside the `getJson()` function.

Comment: Followed up you code and i saw how you use it so scratch what i said - just to be sure log the url when you call `getJson()`

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I have log in the doInbackground(), but also added it to getJson(). The url is the same.

Comment: Is data in recycler view completely different?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos When app starts Recycler view gets items from db in right order. From last (sorted by id DESC). But after returning from another activity, it gets not last items, and order is wrong

Comment: Didn't get the last part you mentioned, but to make my question clearer - when the app starts it fetches and shows the data correctly. If you change activity and go back to that activity which fetchs the data then, as you said, data is wrong, is that data completely wrong - or for example non-ordered?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos i'm going to log  id's of the items, maybe it'll help to understand whats going on

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos

 So, App started:
10759, 
10758, 
10757, 
10756, 
10755, 
10751, 
10750, 
10749, 
10747, 
10746, 


Scrolling :

10721, 
10718, 
10715, 
10714, 
10712, 
10711, 
10710, 
10709, 
10708, 
10707, 


Going to another activity and coming back:

10747, 
10746, 
10743, 
10739, 
10732, 
10731, 
10730, 
10725, 
10724, 
10721,

Comment: Well i really can't help with just those numbers - what are you thinking now that you see the ID's ? (You know better the functionality that you want to achieve) . What is the expected output?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos expected output is the output when the app starts. I analysed those id's and find some interesting: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzJgB9J89goqVUNEa0ZXdmpQaUk
But still can't understand why it happens.

Comment: What happens if user scrolls all the time? I think the problem is in the async task. Try to create a boolean `isFetchingDataNow` : false by default . Set it to `true` right after calling `getJson`. Inside `getJson` don't do anything unless `isFecthingDataNow` is `false` . `isFetchingDataNow` should become false when async task ends.

Comment: I think its connected with wrong data that goes to 
mItemRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved
mItemRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted

Comment: I think the best would be to try both and see what happens!

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos `isFetchingDataNow` must be a global variable?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I noticed that if change jsonUrl and add a paremeter to the end (e.g. /android/jsongetdata.php?yearStart=1991) this problem disappears

Comment: Updated. It also disappears if change limit in php (e.g. $sql .= $limitFrom;
$sql .= ", 10;";  ------->   $sql .= $limitFrom;
$sql .= ", 17;";)

Comment: So what does that mean - did you solve the problem or understood why it occurs?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos unfortunately i didn't understand why it occurs

Comment: Break it down to step by step - debug it - otherwise with all these functions together it won't be that easy! Try by making one request - one query and show the results..just to be sure that the query returns what you need and then add funcionality